# Using Environment Variables in an AD Profile Path

Tags: environment-variables, user-profiles

When I set a profile in an AD object, I need to use a predefined environment variable, %BUILDID%. So the path would be \SVR-STAFF\Profiles$\%BUILDID%\Administrator.v2 ...

But the path doesn't work. If you put it into the run box or explorer box, it works perfect and if you change the AD profile path to \SVR-STAFF\Profiles$\Windows7\Administrator.v2 it works perfect. The path should resolve to this on some of my machines, depending on the variable.

Why isn't this working and how can it work?

Thanks
Ed

Comment: I've never heard of %BUILDID%. Is that a custom variable? If so, I'm fairly certain that it can't be used as it won't be recognized by Windows as a valid variable for the profile path.

Comment: It is a custom variable. It has been used at a site I used to work at, but I have no access to it anymore. Surely because it has been declared, it can be used?

Comment: [This](http://blogs.technet.com/b/askds/archive/2013/07/31/roaming-profile-compatibility-the-windows-7-to-windows-8-challenge.aspx) would suggest it should work, but I can't get it to

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer. When creating the variable in a Group Policy, make sure you say 'Create' and not 'Update'. The variable is then held through reboots, and the PC does not have to wait for the gpupdate to run.